# Using PKCS11 with NSS for Java encryption: java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed

Tags: java, ioexception, pkcs#11, nss

I am trying to set up Java to use NSS for doing some various encryption routines. I understand the JCE necessary to offload these routines to NSS is PKCS11. I have compiled all the NSS binaries, and moved each of the resulting shared objects to /usr/lib/nss:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/nss/
libfreebl3.so  libnss3.so     libnssdbm3.so     libnssutil3.so  libplds4.so   libsoftokn3.so
libnspr4.so    libnssckbi.so  libnsssysinit.so  libplc4.so      libsmime3.so  libsqlite3.so
```

the nss.cfg file I am using is as follows:

```
name=NSS
nssLibraryDirectory=/usr/lib/nss
nssDbMode=noDb
attributes=compatibility
```

However, when running the application, this is the output:

```
java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: libsqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory/usr/lib/nss/libsoftokn3.so
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.<init>(PKCS11.java:138)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:151)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:313)
    ... 5 more
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Looks like library loading problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss/+bug/315096

Comment: Thanks Konstantin! You are absolutely right. It turns out I needed to set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/lib/nss and then everything worked.